# Are multiple async_resolve calls with different query objects to a single resolver in BOOST::ASIO OK?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Am I supposed to have one resolver per active query, or is it OK to call async_resolve multiple times with different query objects?

Answer (score 0):

**No** it is not ok to use a resolver and invoke `async_resolve` while a previous query is still active. The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/resolver.html) states concurrent use of a resolver is not thread safe

> *Thread Safety*
>
> **Distinct objects**: Safe.
>
> **Shared objects**: Unsafe.

Comment: Thanks, but since it is an asynchronous call, the calls wouldn't be from different threads, they would be from the same thread, so thread safety doesn't really apply...